# Polymer 0.8 throws error

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I was trying out polymer tutorial, this is working fine in polymer 0.5.4 and not working with polymer 0.8

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="post-card.html">
  <style>
   html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body unresolved>
      <post-card>
        <img width="70" height="70"
          src="../images/avatar-07.svg">
        <h2>Another Developer</h2>
        <p>I'm composing with shadow DOM!</p>
      </post-card>
 </body>
</html>
```

and post-card.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="post-card">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .card-header {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header h2'; }
    .card-header ::content h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header img'; }
    .card-header ::content img {
      width: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    </style>

    <!-- CARD CONTENTS GO HERE -->
    <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>
    </div>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

in bower.json if i chage from 0.8.0 to 0.5.4 it works. Any idea why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things have changed from Polymer 0.5 to Polymer 0.8, and nearly all the apis that were present in 0.5 will not work with 0.8.

**The best way to rewrite your source would be like:**

index.html needs no change

But post-card.html needs a rework:

```
<dom-module id="post-card">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .card-header {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header h2'; }
    .card-header ::content h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header img'; }
    .card-header ::content img {
      width: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    </style>
  <template>
    <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({is: "post-card"});
</script>
```

A lot has changed over in this alpha release of Polymer:

It's not feasible to mention all the changes in Polymer 0.8 because it's changing all the time.

Please refer to this documentation by Google for more info on Polymer 0.8:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html